# Why does Scanner class not "need" to be closed after reading a text file? (no resource leak warning)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

If I use `System.in` or use a `String` as the argument in a Scanner object's constructor i.e. `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`, I get a resource leak warning from my IDE that I need to close `scan`.

However, if I use it to read a file, i.e. `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));`, I don't receive a warning to close `scan`.

Why does this happen?

Edit:

Example below:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
        System.out.println(scan.next());
        // no warning from IDE on scan
    }
}
```

Edit 2: When the `File` object is initialized separately and before the `Scanner` object, the "resource leak" warning finally shows up.

Comment: You should. Not closing the second form is a resource leak. Not closing `System.in` is not.

Comment: I see warnings in both cases. Maybe you're doing the second in try with resources or closing it somewhere? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. I see a warning in eclipse and it definitely should be closed. Something is wrong with your IDE.